# Extract name of sum in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have the following DataFrame called *df*:

```
KEY_ID  READY   STEADY      GO
001     Yes     Maybe       123
002     No      Maybe       123
003     Yes     Sometimes   234
004     Yes     Later       234
005     No      Sometimes   345
```

I use df.count() to see how many times a value is filled in which is 5 every time:

```
KEY_ID  5
READY   5
STEADY  5
GO      5
```

But I would also like to see how many times the values in column STEADY are used. I do this with `abc = df['STEADY'].value_counts()` which gives me:

```
Sometimes  2
Maybe      2
Later      1
```

With a for loop I can extract the information of the values in abc which I just created with value_counts() as follows:

```
for i in abc:
    print(i)
```

However, I tried several methods, including

```
for i,j in enumerate(abc):
    print(i); print(j)
```

to get the names of *Sometimes, Maybe, Later* as well as I don't want to type them manually. How do I extract these names of the value_counts() values?

Comment: You are not providing enough information.  There is no way to  get anything that looks like your summation with `DataFrame.sum()` if you have variable named `DataFrame` that looks like what you show.  Notice that all the answers are assuming you meant to groupby.  Please clarify so other readers aren't confused.

Comment: @probs you HAVE to tell us how your starting data is organized. You are getting answers where ppl are trying to guess. Clarify your question.

Comment: edited, sorry for the unclear question before

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `groupby()` ?

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [['Apple', 1], ['Orange', 1], ['Apple', 2], ['Orange', 1], ['Apple', 3], ['Orange', 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.columns = ['fruit', 'amount']

df.groupby('fruit').sum()
```

Comment: Hi Jan, no I just want to extract the names of "Apple" and "Orange" which are already present when you do a 'Dataframe.sum' in Pandas

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
rowdata = [['Apple', 1], ['Orange', 1], ['Apple', 2], ['Orange', 1], ['Apple', 3],['Orange', 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(rowdata)
df.groupby(0).sum()
```

This will give like a data frame which is given below,

```
        1
0
Apple   6
Orange  3
```

But just `df.sum()` will give like this,

```
0    AppleOrangeAppleOrangeAppleOrange
1                                    9
```

**I hope you are expecting like the first one..**

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
In [339]: df
Out[339]:
     name  val
0   Apple    1
1  Orange    1
2   Apple    2
3  Orange    1
4   Apple    3
5  Orange    1

In [340]: df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['val'].sum()
Out[340]:
     name  val
0   Apple    6
1  Orange    3

In [341]: df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['val'].sum()['name']
Out[341]:
0     Apple
1    Orange
Name: name, dtype: object

In [342]: df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['val'].sum()['name'].tolist()
Out[342]: ['Apple', 'Orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want filter first by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (df)
        A  B
0   Peach  3
1    Pear  6
2   Apple  1
3  Orange  1
4   Apple  2
5  Orange  1
6   Apple  3
7  Orange  1

df1 = df[df['A'].isin(['Apple','Orange'])]
print (df1)
        A  B
2   Apple  1
3  Orange  1
4   Apple  2
5  Orange  1
6   Apple  3
7  Orange  1
```

Then `groupby` and [aggregate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) `sum`:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].sum()
print (df2)
        A  B
0   Apple  6
1  Orange  3
```

---

Another solution is `groupby` and aggregate `first` and then select only values by list:

```
df1 = df.groupby('A')['B'].sum()
df2 = df1.loc[['Apple','Orange']].reset_index()
print (df2)
        A  B
0   Apple  6
1  Orange  3
```